# SESSION not working with Sencha Touch 2 and Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, coldfusion-9

I am calling the APIs of my web-service to run the Sencha touch application.
When I hit the login API directly from browser, it sets the SESSION variable that I can access later.

But when I call the same API diagrammatically from my Sencha Touch Application it logs me in successfully but it doesn't set the SESSION variables. i.e. I cannot access the session variables in further APIs.

I am not sure if the issue is on Client side or on Server side. Any thoughts?

Comment: I doubt it is on the server. CF can't tell one client from another (unless you added code to do that). Is the Sencha Touch app passing the session cookies back to the server?

Comment: @JasonDean No, sencha app isn't passing anything like that. Can you please explain a little. What is needed to be done on Client side and what on server side. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have no idea what needs to be done client-side to make it pass the cookies, but CF needs the cookies to maintain the session state.

Comment: Is this application running in the browser or from a native app?

Comment: @JasonDean Currently I am running it from google chrome (for testing). I haven't deployed this app yet on phone.

Comment: Then sorry, I really have no idea. It should be Sencha's job to work with the cookies. Perhaps Sencha requires that you do it manually. Or perhaps it expects you to work with RESTful APIs and maintain state on the client.

Comment: @JasonDean Yes, you seem to be correct according to my findings so far. Thanks for trying to help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response of Login API I also returned `#SESSION.CFID#` and `#SESSION.CFTOKEN#`

Now with every API I am sending these variable: ?CFID=123&CFTOKEN=334455

And finally the Coldfusion can recognize my session :)

Comment: Session variables require that the client cookies be set with the session ID or that the IDs are passed in the URL.